# Delete duplicates from another directory recursively

Tags: filenames, duplicate-files

(N.B. There are many similar questions (e.g. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32651413/575530), [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/524310/160404), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21337587/575530), and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32489574/575530)) but they either assume that the directory structure is one-deep, or the answers are more complex multi-line scripts.)

This is my situation:

```
.
├── to_keep
│   ├── a
│   │   └── duplicate1.txt
│   └── b
│       ├── duplicate2.txt
│       └── unique1.txt
└── to_purge
    ├── c
    │   └── duplicate1.txt
    └── d
        ├── duplicate2.txt
        └── unique2.txt
```

Is there a simple one line script that will use the basenames found in `to_keep` (and its sub-directories) and remove files with the same name from `to_purge` (and its sub-directories)?

The two attempts I have made both fail.

(In both I have used `find -print` to test the command, with the intention of swapping it to `find -delete` when it is working.)

The first uses `$()`:

```bash
find ./to_purge/ -print -name $(find ./to_keep/ -type f -printf "%f\n")
```

```
find: paths must precede expression: `duplicate2.txt'
```

The second uses `xargs`:

```bash
find ./to_keep/ -type f -printf "%f\n" | xargs --max-args=1 find ./to_purge/ -print -name
```

```
./to_purge/
./to_purge/c
./to_purge/c/duplicate1.txt
./to_purge/d
./to_purge/d/duplicate2.txt
./to_purge/d/unique2.txt
./to_purge/
./to_purge/c
./to_purge/c/duplicate1.txt
./to_purge/d
./to_purge/d/duplicate2.txt
./to_purge/d/unique2.txt
./to_purge/
./to_purge/c
./to_purge/c/duplicate1.txt
./to_purge/d
./to_purge/d/duplicate2.txt
./to_purge/d/unique2.txt
```

Neither attempt works. What have I got wrong?

Comment: so you want to remove every duplicated files ***based on filename*** from any directories if there is one in `to_keep` directory?

Comment: @αғsнιη exactly, as you say I "want to remove every duplicated files _based on filename_ from any directories if there is one in the `to_keep` directory"

Comment: Is there a reason you want a "one-line script" and not something more rubust that you could re-use later?

Comment: @Kusalananda You ask "Is there a reason you want a 'one-line script'"? Yes, if I was to write a multi-line script I would write it in a programming language I am more familiar with. I find bash useful for short one-line tasks, but for longer scripts I'd swap to Python (or some-such)

Answer (score 1):

The following will find all regular files in or under `./to_keep` and will call an in-line `sh -c` script with these in batches.  For each batch of pathnames, the in-line script will call `find` once to find the regular files under `./to_purge` that have the same names.  The pathnames of these files under `./to_purge` will be printed (to delete them, add `-delete` after `-print`).

```bsh
find to_keep -type f -exec sh -c '
    for pathname do
        set -- "$@" -o -name "${pathname##*/}"
        shift
    done; shift
    find to_purge \( "$@" \) -type f -print' sh {} +
```

or, as requested, on one line:

```bsh
find to_keep -type f -exec sh -c 'for pathname do set -- "$@" -o -name "${pathname##*/}"; shift; done; shift; find to_purge \( "$@" \) -type f -print' sh {} +
```

The in-line script constructs an OR-list of `-name` tests for the `find` command that it uses on its last line. The loop constructs this list in the positional parameters from the filename component of each pathname that the outer `find` has passed to it.

This deals with all allowed filenames, including filenames containing spaces, tabs and newlines.  Again, to *delete* files, add `-delete` (or `-exec rm {} +`) after `-print` in the code.

As a short script that takes the "keep directory" and "purge directory" as command line arguments:

```bsh
#!/bin/sh

keepdir=$1
purgedir=$2

find "$keepdir" -type f -exec sh -c '
    dir=$1; shift
    for pathname do
        set -- "$@" -o -name "${pathname##*/}"
        shift
    done; shift
    find "$dir" \( "$@" \) -type f -print' sh "$purgedir" {} +
```

The only issue with this code is that it will use the names in one directory as *patterns* for finding the names of files in the other directory.  This means that if a file in the first directory is called `*`, all files in the second directory are removed.  You can fix that protecting the filenames in the inner `find`:

```bsh
for pathname do
    sane=$( printf "%s\n" "${pathname##*/}" | sed "s/[[*?]/\\&/g" )
    set -- "$@" -o -name "$sane"
    shift
done; shift
```

This modification to the loop in the in-line `sh -c` script escapes the `[`, `*` and `?` characters (otherwise used as filename globbing patterns).  The script would now not deal with filenames that *end* in a newline (due to the command substitution used), but that might arguably be something that one could live with.

Comment: The question asks for a simple one-line script. Have you opted for a longer script because there is no simpler alternative? If so it would be great if the answer mentioned that.

Comment: @dumbledad It's a single `find` command. You can easily write it all out on one line if you wanted to, but I didn't do so here as it would be difficult to read here.

Comment: @dumbledad See updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

Typical, no sooner posted than I find an answer!

```bash
find ./to_keep/ -type f -exec basename '{}' \; | xargs --max-args=1 find ./to_purge/ -name | xargs --max-args=1 rm
```

I will not accept this as the answer since I do not yet know what is wrong with my previous attempts.

Comment: This appears to try to remove directories in `to_purge` that has the same names as files under `to_keep`. It will also delete the two separate files `hello` and `world` under `to_purge` if there is a file called `hello world` under `to_keep`.

Comment: That will break horribly if your file names contain spaces. (A name of `apple sauce` would delete files named `apple` or `sauce` but not `apple sauce` itself)